# CMake, how to set different value in a configure_file in Build vs Install

Tags: c, cmake, lua

I have a simple [CMake project](https://github.com/Kamranaghl/app.git) with CTest and CPack. It uses the Lua C API to load and execute an script file called script.lua.
This script will be in different location when built vs when installed/packed, it's location would be:

```
[build]  : ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/scripts
[install]: ../scripts (relative to app which is in bin directory)
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to have install step regenerate configure_file then rebuild using new configure_file and only then proceed to do the normal install step and of course revert the configure_file back to it's original state afterwards.

Any help regarding this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that CMake's `configure_file` command has its full effect during the execution of the `cmake` program.  It has no representation in generated makefiles, or whatever other build system components `cmake` generates.  Thus, if you want to configure a file differently for installation than for pre-installation testing,

1. You would need to perform completely separate builds (starting with executing `cmake`) for the two cases, and
2. You would need to use some attribute of the `cmake` command line or execution environment to convey the wanted information, such as using a `-D` option to define a CMake variable on the command line.

I advise you not to pursue this route.  Aside from being overcomplicated, it's also poor form to install a different build of the software than is tested.

You have a variety of alternatives that could serve better.  Among those are

- Give the program itself the ability to accept a custom location for the Lua script.  That is, make it recognize a command-line argument or environment variable that serves this purpose.  Make use of that during pre-installation testing.
- If indeed the program is using a relative path to locate the script at runtime, then just (have CMake) put a copy of the script at the appropriate location in the build tree, so that the program will find it normally during testing.